# iOS UI Custom button images

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm developing a iOS app that is using custom UIButtons with round shape. I wanted to add Image to these buttons and would like to know if I use IB to select an image from my project, do I have to also worry about 2x retina images for retina display?. What should be the image size for both non-retina and retina devices (all iPhones (including iphone 5) and iPad including mini) when I embedded them from IB?

Is there a best resource available on the Internet to get these pngs files for buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should use all the images. you should just add the images with proper names to the resources folder. And just select the non-retina image rest the compiler will take care of.

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

The above link will help you with the images sizes

Answer (score 1):

It is easy. Goto interface builder and on the right hand panel you will see this -

[image]

All you need to do is first configure your button as `custom` then include a image file in your project through xcode and then you can select that image in the dropdown in background or image property.

Note that all this is possible to do through code also, its just that IB makes it interactive. Hope this helps.